# TextView Html Link Activity

Tags: android

I am using this code to open activity in `html` from in `TextView`.It is working fine.

i.e. click on 'open Activity' it opens the activity.

but my question is how can i send data or parameter with this??

```
   txtLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLink);

    txtLink.setText(Html
            .fromHtml("<b>text3:</b>  Text with a "
                    + "<a href=\***"com.example.textviewlink:/linkActivty/\">Open Activity</a>*** "
                    + "created in the Java source code using HTML.<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google.com</a>"));
    txtLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

how can i send extra parameter in above code so i can use it in target activity?

Answer (score 3):

```
String text = "Visit my blog <a href=\"http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/\">mysite</a> or run the <a href=\"sherif-activity://myactivity?author=sherif&nick=king\">myactivity</a> callback";
```

Using Intent in your called activity.

```
 String author = getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("author");  
 String nick = getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("nick");
```

Look ath this [link](http://www.sherif.mobi/2011/09/html-and-activity-links-in-textview.html).

Answer (score -3):

for example :

Layout

```
<TextView 
            android:id="@+id/link_web"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:autoLink="web"               
            android:text="@string/link_web"/>
```

Activity

```
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("http://www.google.com"));
```

Comment: The question isn't about a link to Google's web site. It's about a link to an Activity.